# Phonetic search with Solr, for Brazilian Portuguese

Tags: solr, localization

we are implementing Solr as the new internal search engine for our website.

Most features are running just fine, others are in the adjusting and calibration phase.

But there is one feature that I'm not finding any good documentation over the web. So here it goes:

- how can I implement phonetic search and suggest with Solr, for brazilian portuguese language?

I was able already to create an index, using the official stemming tokenizer
http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Language+Analysis#LanguageAnalysis-BrazilianPortuguese

But the match against uses parsers adapted to understand everything as english. That is where the problem lies.

Tutorial, documentation, how to or reply are welcome.

Comment: can you send your field definition?

Comment: could you describe the problem you are trying to address using phonetic approach?

Comment: @phani, we'd like to address basically misspelled words without creating a synonyms dictionary manually.

Answer (score 0):

you should use SynonymFilterFactory : [solr documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory)

```
#example of synonym definition for brazilian's living people kkk :)
copa=>futebol
football=> futebol
brasil, brazil => brasil
```

Caution : do use this filter on index time . It will have no effect on query time saddly :(